# What does "get some walking in" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ... read a good book every now and then, get some walking in, and try
> and live together in peace and harmony with people of all creeds and
> nations.

Could you tell me please the meaning of "get some walking in"?

Does it simply mean "go for a walk"?

Or [walk in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/walk-in) here means"allowing people to come without planning to do so in advance"?

The fuller text:

> Now, here’s the meaning of life … Well, it’s nothing very special,
> really. Uh, try and be nice to people, avoid eating fat, read a good
> book every now and then, get some walking in, and try and live
> together in peace and harmony with people of all creeds and nations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase is not *walk in* but *get some X in*.

It means "do some X",  but with a bit more - it has a suggestion of X being a goal to achieve. This might be a matter of fitting it into a busy schedule, but you might also say "I'm going away for the weekend - I want to get some walking in".

So in this context, "get some walking in" is seen as a desirable end, something to be fitted into one's life-plan.